# Tell me how to replace python data, How can I read the a.txt file and make it in the following format?

Tags: python, hive

Tell me how to replace python data

a.txt

```
abcd.com     0.0
*       6.6999306E7
asdf.com    1.50744025E8
asfd.df.com    1.93139033E8
fdsa.com      9.07938122E8
bank.com     2.638989462E9
fire.com       4.151822166E9
ms.com       7.026079907E9
```

How can I read the a.txt file and make it in the following format?
Output result :

```
['abcd.com', 0], 
['*', 66999306], 
['asdf.com', 150744025], 
['asfd.df.com', 193139033], 
['fdsa.com', 907938122], 
['bank.com', 2638989462], 
['fire.com', 4151822166],
['ms.com', 7026079907]
```

Comment: What do these things have to do with each other?

Comment: `print("[\'Platinum\', 21.45],"*7)`? ... No, seriously, it is impossible to understand this question. Please edit.

Comment: I tried to replace the file one line at a time, but it did not work.
a.readline()

Comment: what is the output? a list of lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file = open('a.txt', 'r')

l = []
for line in file:
    l.append( line.split())
```

Then if you want the second part to be integer, you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
l = [ [i[0], int(float(i[1]))] for i in l]
```

output

```
[['abcd.com', 0], 
['*', 66999306], 
['asdf.com', 150744025], 
['asfd.df.com', 193139033], 
['fdsa.com', 907938122], 
['bank.com', 2638989462], 
['fire.com', 4151822166],
['ms.com', 7026079907] ]
```

Comment: you forgot a closing parenthesis and a bracket

Comment: @Ev.Kounis thanks mate !

Comment: l = [ [i[0], int(i[1] for i in l]
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: l = [ [i[0], int(float(i[1]))] for i in l]

I changed it like this. Thank you very much.!

Comment: Tbaki !           ['abcd.com', 23.45, ' ' ] .   ['abcd.com', 23.45, ' ' ] 
Can I make a list of three values?

Comment: @kyoungwoncho, changed it in my reponse, glad i helped !

Comment: @kyoungwoncho What do you mean ?

Comment: @kyoungwoncho you mean adding '' at the end ?

Comment: ['ms.com', 7026079907, 'value'] , ['fire.com', 4151822166, 'value2'] ...

Can I put three values ​​in a list like this?

Comment: Fixed using i [2]. Thank you :)

Comment: @kyoungwoncho Sure, it'll just change the list comprehension

Comment: @kyoungwoncho no problem, it'll feel more natural when you'll get used to it, good luck. : )